# Clean up of [speed] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I draw your attention to the [speed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed) tag.

Currently, there are 11 questions. There is, of course, no tag wiki or excerpt.

The questions are on a variety of topics.

- 2 are closed webapp recommendation questions asking for a fast dictionary and a broadband speed test
- 1 is about speeding up Gmail search
- several are about YouTube, either playing videos at different speeds or about video quality on high-speed connections
- 1 is about the limits on tests at a connection speed utility
- 1 is about improving performance on a large number of complex formulas in Google Sheets

I suggest this is the very definition of a "meta tag".

Using [the guidance here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

- it does *not* describe the contents of the question and it is definitely ambiguous
- the concept is only very tenuously related to the topic of this site
- it doesn't seem to add any meaningful information to the questions it's on; certainly there is no expert on "speed"
- its meaning varies depending on context

It should be burninated.

Comment: Agreed.  We can probably just edit it off and let the system get rid of it once there are no more questions.  I don't think it needs to be blacklisted.

Comment: Not looking to blacklist it, just get rid of it. Want to be sure to get consensus before proceeding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tag has been removed from all questions and the tag has been removed from the system.